# Verify email address before login

Tags: c#, xamarin, parse-platform

I trying to verify the email address of user before their login. However when I try to use the following code, it will prompt out error thus i could not verify the user's email address.

```
var user await ParseUser.LogInAsync(EmailU, PasswordU);
if (user["emailVerified"] = true )
```

This is the error message:

> Error CS0818  Implicitly-typed variables must be initialized
>
> Error CS0136  A local or parameter named 'user' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter
>
> Error CS1002  ; expected

```
private async void BtnLoginUser_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string EmailU = txtEmailU.Text.ToString();
    string PasswordU = txtPwU.Text.ToString();
    var user = new ParseUser();
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailU))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Please Enter Email", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            return;
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PasswordU))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Please Enter Password", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            return;
        }
        else 
        {
            ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

            mDialog.SetTitle("Please Wait");
            mDialog.SetMessage("Loging");
            mDialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            mDialog.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
            mDialog.Show();                    
            var user await ParseUser.LogInAsync(EmailU, PasswordU);
            if (user["emailVerified"] = true )
            {
                StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Please Verify", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                return;
            }
            
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ep)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Some Error Occured " + ep.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
```

Comment: You're missing a '=' by `var user = await ParseUser.LogInAsync(EmailU, PasswordU)`
Also, what type is your 'user'? It looks like you're trying to access it like a Dictionary

Comment: "var user = await ...."

Comment: I have tried to put a '=' but i will get the error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'. what is this problem?

Comment: user["emailVerified"] == true - you need two "=" for comparison

Comment: i got put two "=" but will get the error that i mentioned just now

Comment: what type is user?  is user["emailVerified"] a bool?

Comment: yes, it is bool

Comment: if it was then it wouldn't throw this error.  What is the type of the user object?

Answer (score 0):

Comments in code next to related lines.

The CS0136 error is because you "shadowed" `user` later by re-declaring it `var user...` I would think this should be the same declaration used, so remove the first one or remove the `var` from the second one.

Also, you need to *assign* the `await` to user, so you are missing the `=`.

Finally, you don't want to use `=` in the next `if` statement, you want to test if the value is true. You could use `== true`, but the idiomatic way would be to use `if (user["emailVerified"])`.

```
private async void BtnLoginUser_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  string EmailU = txtEmailU.Text.ToString();
  string PasswordU = txtPwU.Text.ToString();
  var user = new ParseUser();
  try
  {
    // ...
    else 
    {
        // ...
        mDialog.Show();                  
        // need = to assign to user
        // also remove var since already declared above (this fixes two errors)
        // OR remove the above declaration!  
        user = await ParseUser.LogInAsync(EmailU, PasswordU);
        // could be == true, but should just be user["emailVerified"]
        if (user["emailVerified"])
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Please Verify", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            return;
        }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ep)
  {
     Toast.MakeText(this, "Some Error Occured " + ep.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
  }
}
```

**Note:** It is quite possible that `user["emailVerified"]` is not a native .Net bool and you may need to do some sort of conversion, parsing, or other test. You would need to look at the documentation for the API and/or inspect the type returned by the call to determine that.